# How can I avoid duplication in a join query using Sequel with Postgres on Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sinatra, sequel

I want to do a simple join. I have two tables: "candidates" and "notes".

Not all candidates have notes written about them, some candidates have more than one note written about them. The linking fields are `id` in the candidates table and `candidate_id` in the notes table. The query is:

```
people = candidates.where(:industry => industry).where("country = ?", country).left_outer_join(:notes, :candidate_id => :id).order(Sequel.desc(:id)).map do |row|
  {
    :id => row[:id],
    :first => row[:first],
    :last => row[:last],
    :designation => row[:designation],
    :company => row[:company],
    :email => row[:email],
    :remarks => row[:remarks],
    :note => row[:note]
  } 
end
```

It works kind of fine and gets all the specified candidates from the candidates table and the notes from the notes table but where there is more than one note it repeats the name of the candidate. In the resulting list, person "abc" appears twice or three times depending on the number of notes associated with that person.

I am not actually printing the notes in the HTML result just a "tick" if that person has notes and "--" if no notes.

I want the person's name to appear only once. I have tried adding `distinct` in every conceivable place in the query but it made no difference.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for distinct to work, you need to make sure you are only selecting columns that you want to be distinct on.  You could try adding this to the query

```
.select(:candidates__id, :first, :last, :designation, :company, :email, :remarks, Sequel.as({:notes=>nil}).as(:notes)).distinct
```

But you may be better off using a subselect instead of a join to check for the existence of notes (assuming you are using a decent database):

```
candidates.where(:industry => industry, :country=>country).select_append(Sequel.as({:id=>DB[:notes].select(:candidate_id)}, :note)).order(Sequel.desc(:id)).map do |row|
  { :id => row[:id], :first => row[:first], :last => row[:last], :designation => row[:designation], :company => row[:company], :email => row[:email], :remarks => row[:remarks], :note => row[:note] } 
end
```